# VS code ghostly autocomplete between the lines of code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete

When I type I get those annoying suggestions inside VS code and I don't know how to get rid of them. Any help would be appreciated.

This kind of auto complete appears

[image: 1]

Tried to change suggestions and autocomplete settings on Intellisense, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

And I found the answer finally. The steps are the following:

1. Go to settings > extensions > Typescript and disable:
2. Javascript inlay hints on all options.

or...unisnatll the extension Typescript. That's it. The ghost writing is gone!